# Google places api not working properly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm not getting search results while using the Google api for places. There are also no ratings coming like a week ago. Im getting results for far off places and not nearby. Has Google changing the api or should I wait a little more for Google to give a good places api. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. Google changed the Places API in late June 2014 to deprecate the `reference` and `id` fields in favor of a single `place_id`. They also changed the detail level in the JSON response. For instance, not including the `name` parameter in your call like this...

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&key=YOURKEY
```

...returns results that look like this:

```
"html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CoQC8gAAALD7H9pFpjSrFHDEn0_rzBef77uvO3hAvsO9u344Jh05RIsiVtkMvAbgZaYbp15lus4mOIbrWtbk-SIJ9j2B5ankZiTt9ZvJBUwOhjkBsCopBR_EhQQO4ZZciVQGFYVl-Zu4Y7vHSx6mKFzZ5rNeqVdFbBOfTeptNIjjs3re9EEkmqa_gFZ60J7DTw0Qgig_Vekq9I0aMF62Y3a3ZvAb4ElFpapxkvkHRRW_r6fYLR7L77JHzxheL_BVuNqDhM8F_lZl9gwe9g5vehb_xkwSOnIl001Ybdntipuyf_dmCpBg_58Vv0Xm0Z8MvNqLSeaE6B5vZXspYxZWqtHCN5andLUSEMgSnJKHtPzxTDkmZcmgulIaFFSiA6dQUakJXIEQCkulMheOBV2t",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.871194,
               "lng" : 151.19891
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "6237ce126ba1afabd5985b059d3d1eca6e9ee0da",
         "name" : "Blue Fish",
         "place_id" : "ChIJBaqDDzquEmsRcCI5e-3rStM",
         "reference" : "CnRsAAAAibazLaEzCLq4fMIASFHDGG81Ls_hY5ycFP-GRfZP5dKRuLblqe8qrzf5BOKVZOtbRwNQ2PN34sQv5o0H_kL_LEZhKPFmpMz7qkAj6a262KGICKoxTznqRILF2bVZVk7SED0qRnpiyo_A304g30itnhIQBmp1tv7ZoYnOGnrqhtTXzhoU2HDzURqpVMfmpAYoEqbVDJg8J9s",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Harbourside Shopping Centre/287 Darling Drive, Sydney CBD"
      }
```

Whereas if you include the name parameter, like this...

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=YOURKEY
```

...your results return a more detailed response:

```
"html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.870775,
               "lng" : 151.199025
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/travel_agent-71.png",
         "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
         "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 270,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAOCqDF9u4_e5cEPJq0J3M-37u9fa4IfMJK7-SceKf98mkZAnSbVLPUN-PoHBeW8_32daeNBA-H9dI3xuIERAyBAXfmXB0MbO26ITj0ryvJgHe6V6m2GhxJXFVpv_XSMBp8XsghrHXhfWFidj8p4WCtBIQetaqvTH1oI28Nsd-iHXqFxoU8m00lJGS1J6FJMfQl-kqZjXbf8s",
               "width" : 519
            }
         ]
```

As you can see, the more detailed response provides rating, opening hours, photos, etc., but also requires use of a more detailed URL string.

My app used to pull one set of restaurant data, then pass the information anywhere I needed it (from a TableViewController to a DetailView for example). With this new change, the only band-aid solution we can devise is to make two separate calls to the API. One to retrieve the basic upper layer of information from the JSON object for my TableViewController, the second (after tapping on the cell to create the new URL string, including the `name` parameter) to fetch the additional more detailed information like rating and opening hours. As you can imagine, this solution will increase the number of API calls tenfold as your users would essentially make an API call every time they reviewed the details of a place. No bueno.

As a result, we're researching other place indexes, such as the built-in Apple MKLocalSearch, which returns a similar, but not identical set of information as Google Places API. Maybe MKLocalSearch will suit your needs.

If others have found a better solution to this change, I think we'd all be open to it.

### **EDIT**

It looks like they want us to use the place_id returned by the text search or nearby search to make another call to get place details. See [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details).